# Rails 3: Contact form to send messages from User Profiles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, email, contacts

I worked through some basic tutorials on Rails 3. The goal is a community-website on abilities and activities. I am using Devise for authentication. The creation of user profiles with avatars worked well (thanks to paperclip).

As a next step, I want to enable registered users to **send an e-mail to a user from his (or her) profile page**. I found a great tutorial on creating a contact form using Google Apps:
http://matharvard.ca/posts/2011/aug/22/contact-form-in-rails-3/

The mailer class in this tutorial looks like:

```
class NotificationsMailer < ActionMailer::Base

  default :from => "noreply@youdomain.dev"
  default :to => "you@youremail.dev"

  def new_message(message)
    @message = message
    mail(:subject => "[YourWebsite.tld] #{message.subject}")
  end

end
```

My question: What is the best way to **replace you@youremail.dev** with the receivers E-Mail-Address? (from the User-Model)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the `new_message` to accept the user (or list of users) to whom you want to send the email. Or an array of email addresses if you want to. Then pass the receiver's email address to the `mail` method as the `:to` option.

```
def new_message(receiver, message)
  @message = message
  mail(:subject => "[YourWebsite.tld] #{message.subject}",
       :to => receiver.email_address) # or something similar
end
```

Then you can invoke your mailer like this

```
NotificationEmail.new_message(a_user, a_message).deliver
```

To read the API see [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html) or [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionMailer/Base) (I prefer APIdock).

Also a more comprehensive guide on ActionMailer is available [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html). If you are new to Rails, you can find more guides [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/).

Comment: It works great, thanks! To inform the controller to which User it should send the message, I added a hidden field to the message form. Like: <%= form.hidden_field :user_id, :value => @user.id %>

Comment: @user1133942 great! I don't know much about the particularities of your app, buy note that a malicious user can change the value of the hidden field and then the message can be sent to someone else. So, if this is not acceptable, you should prevent it from happening.

Comment: I am using CanCan to limit user rights and will permit only logged in members to send E-Mails, so the Message Controller will prevent the sending, if the current user has not the necessary rights. But I guess, I have to deal with Rails for a while to see all potential threats. Thanks for the hint! :-)